# Set globstar to act recursively

Tags: terminal, bash

In the answer to question about enable wildcards recursive:
[bash - What expands to all files in current directory recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690809/what-expands-to-all-files-in-current-directory-recursively)

the `globstar` could be activated by `shopt -s globstar`:

I post snippet of the answer as below:

> In order for the double-asterisk glob to work, the `globstar` option needs to be set (default: on):

```
shopt -s globstar
```

From `man bash`:

```
    globstar
                  If set, the pattern ** used in a filename expansion con‐
                  text will match a files and zero or more directories and
                  subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /, only
                  directories and subdirectories match.
```

However, I encounter error when tried it

```
$ shopt -s globstar
-bash: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Using just `shopt` will list all bash specific shell options? How did you install bash4.4.19?

Comment: `brew install bash` @fd0

Comment: OK, you installed a newer version of bash with HomeBrew but haven't changed your shell in the password database (OpenDirectory). When you start a terminal session the application calls `login` which starts the session with the shell listed in the database (bash 3.2.57). When you issue `bash --version` a sub-shell with the newer version of `bash` is run.  You need to change the location with your new version of `bash` in the Users & Groups preferences.

Comment: @fd0 I just changed my Users & Groups shell to brew's bash and am still getting "shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name". Is there another step? thx